# Angular material table: Dynamic sticky columns break the table

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Dynamically adding a mix of sticky and non-sticky columns to mat-table seems to break it. You can see the demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfxahi?file=src/app/table-sticky-columns-example.ts
I suspect that the issue is due to Angular not knowing the actual width of the content in the column, however setting `width` or `min-width` to `.mat-header-cell, .mat-cell` doesn't help. When inspecting the columns you can see that `left` CSS attribute is not set to correct value.

I cannot change the table to use static definitions as it is reused in different scenarios. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the width on `.mat-header-cell` or `.mat-cell`, set `width` and `left` on the columns which are sticky (`.mat-column-<label>`). In order for it to work, the left value needs to be set to at least the width of the previous column:

```css
.mat-column-name {
  width: 110px; 
}
.mat-column-position {
  width: 80px;
  left: 110px !important;
}
```

*Note:* you need to use `!important` since `left` is set on `.mat-header-cell` and `.mat-cell` directly.

If you want to style the sticky columns more dynamically, you can add the styling to your column definition and then use it in the template:

```js
const DEFINITIONS: ColumnDefintion[] = [
  {label: 'name', sticky: true, style: {'width':'100px', 'left':'0px'}},
  {label: 'position', sticky: true, style: {'width':'80px', 'left':'100px'}},
  {label: 'weight'},
  {label: 'symbol'},
]
```

```html
<!-- ... -->
<ng-container *ngIf="colDef.sticky" [matColumnDef]="colDef.label" sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngStyle]="colDef.style">{{colDef.label}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="colDef.style">{{element[colDef.label]}}</td>
</ng-container>
<!-- ... -->
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-multiple-sticky-cols?file=src/app/table-sticky-columns-example.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The solution was quite simple then! A shame you cannot leave the width undefined, so table can resize itself as it sees fit. I guess you cannot calculate how much px you would need to set on each column then. But this should actually be doable by using JS to inspect the column width and then set `left` to proper value?

Comment: @I_Have_A_Name It depends on what look you really want to achieve. You can leave the width undefined, but when scrolling horizontally the width of the first column will be reduced to the value of 'left' of the right adjacent column automatically and the width of the second column won't be changed (you can easily test this with my Stackblitz. Just remove the width definition from `style`).

Comment: Regarding calculated values: I would say that it depends on whether you want the column to be at least as wide as the header, or if you want it to somehow fit the width of the content. If you care about the header, you could multiply the string length of the label with a certain number, add some extra for the padding and use that value as the width. But that would be more of a hack than a flawless solution. The JS approach is probably the better one.

Comment: I agree that JS approach is a way to go, thanks for info!

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem it seems to be a general issue if you play with sticky and dynamic cols.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15885

This worked for me:

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.table) {
        this.table.updateStickyColumnStyles();
    }
}
```

hope it works for you too.